# Лисенер закрывает анимацию на касание CardView в RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android

Такая проблема, настроил анимацию на касание  CardView в RecyclerView и вроде все работает, но 2 проблемы :

1. Когда отключаю слушатель, то анимация работает как нужно, когда
   подключаю слушатель, анимация срабатывает на 5 раз... Я почитал и
   понял, что такое бывает когда слушатели пересекаются, но у меня он
   один... Не пойму в чем ошибся
2. И второе не пойму как поменять цвет самой волны от касания, так как
   по умолчанию волна белого цвета и если `CardView` светлые то эффект
   касания практически не заметен...

Вот код `CardView`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    app:cardElevation="15dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/standard_white"

    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

---- < тут код > ----

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

вот код адаптера

```
public class FriendsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FriendsAdapter.FriendViewHolder> {

List<CardFriend> friends;

public FriendsAdapter(List<CardFriend> friends) {
    this.friends = friends;
}

public static class FriendViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView cv;
    TextView friendName;
    TextView friendNumber;
    ImageView friendPhoto;
    TextView friendEmail;

    FriendViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        friendName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPersonName);
        friendNumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPersonNumber);
        friendPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivPersonPhoto);
        friendEmail = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPersonEmail);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return friends.size();
}

@Override
public FriendViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_friend, viewGroup, false);
    return new FriendViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FriendViewHolder friendViewHolder, int i) {
    friendViewHolder.friendName.setText(friends.get(i).getFriendName());
    friendViewHolder.friendNumber.setText(friends.get(i).getFriendNumber());
    friendViewHolder.friendPhoto.setImageResource(friends.get(i).getPhotoId());
    friendViewHolder.friendEmail.setText(friends.get(i).getFriendEmail());
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}
}
```

Вот код слушателя

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);

    void onLongItemClick(View view, int position);
}

private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && mListener != null) {
                mListener.onLongItemClick(child, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
    View child = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (child != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        mListener.onItemClick(child, view.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
}
}
```

и вот как я устанавливаю слушатель во фрагменте

```
rvFriends.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), rvFriends,
            new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onItemClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }

                @Override
                public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onLongItemClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            })
    );
```

Что сделал не так?

EDIT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="4dp"
android:paddingEnd="8dp"
android:paddingStart="8dp"
android:paddingTop="4dp">

<com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
    android:id="@+id/ripple"
    app:mrl_rippleColor="@color/standard_white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardElevation="15dp">


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что вы пытаетесь аналог подобной либо запилить: [materialRipple](https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple) - Я её зал и конфликтов со слушателями не имел.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Я вот тоже попробовал, вроде `CardView` обернул как описано в этой либе (пример прикрепил к вопросу), но все равно не работает...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб так то вроде либа класная, и цвет рип можно в ней сразу поставить нужный... Но наверное ее нужно не в разметку ставить, а в адаптер... Но я поставил в адаптеор и там она выкидывает ошибку

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вроде получилось через адаптер сделать как в проекте этой либы показано, но с карточками это не очень работает... Карточки имеют паддинги, и получается что рип выходит за границы...

Comment: Поместите библиотечный элемент внутрь карточки. Паддинги внутрь элемента

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Да спасибо! Все заработало)) Была проблема с заменой цвета самой карточки, так как при замене цвета эффект пропадал, но я установил такой параментр app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true" и все в порядке))

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Опубликовал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользовался библиотекой [materialRipple](https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple) , спасибо @ЮрийСПб за совет и все заработало, вот код как это выглядит

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="4dp"
android:paddingEnd="8dp"
android:paddingStart="8dp"
android:paddingTop="4dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="15dp">

    <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
        android:id="@+id/ripple"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/standard_white"
        app:mrl_rippleColor="@color/ntz_background_light_grey"
        app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivPersonPhoto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPersonName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ivPersonPhoto"
                android:text="@string/name"
                android:textColor="@color/black_color"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPersonNumber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvPersonName"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ivPersonPhoto"
                android:text="@string/number"
                android:textColor="@color/black_color" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPersonEmail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvPersonNumber"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ivPersonPhoto"
                android:text="@string/email"
                android:textColor="@color/black_color" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```